# How are public/private keys used in code?

Tags: encryption

I have a question about public key encryption.

Say I have a string: "Hello, everyone."

If I am choosing to use a cipher to encode/encrypt this by just shifting the letters around X places, it is easy to figure out what the key is due to things in the english language like LL, OO, etc.

Taking a key into consideration, which could be a string or a number or whatever else, how does this incorporate into the code I'm writing to make my plain-text string encrypted in such a way that it isn't possible to discern patterns in the encrypted text?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the term "cipher" with the meaning it had up to, say, 1860. While this would be quite appropriate in case of a quick chat with queen Victoria, it so happens that Science has advanced a tiny bit since these times.

Your question is is rather broad since it is, mostly: "that field of cryptography which has occupied thousands of researchers for more than four decades, well, how does it work ?". This *cannot* be answered within the size constraints of this site. Well, I can tell that "it works pretty well" but, beyond that, you are in need of some introductory material on cryptography. For instance, [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0385495323), which is not bad, as far as these things go.